# $p$ and $q$ orthogonal projections in $B(H)$, then the orthogonal projection onto the intersection space is the strong operator limit of $(pq)^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, von-neumann-algebras

$p$ and $q$ orthogonal projections why is it true that the orthogonal projection onto $p(H) \cap q(H)$ is the strong operator limit of $(pq)^n$ ?